# Determine if either of both languages are ambiguous?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm reading the book: Formal Syntax and Semantics of
Programming Languages. I don't understand this exercise:

Consider the following two grammars, each of which generates strings of
correctly balanced parentheses and brackets. Determine if either or both
is ambiguous. The Greek letter `ε` repreents an empty string.

1. `<string> ::= <string> <string> | ( <string> ) |[ <string> ] | ε`
2. `<string> ::= ( <string> ) <string> | [ <string> ] <string> | ε`

Comment: Belongs on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @280Z28 Definitely does not belong on [cstheory.se], that's only for research-level questions. It's on-topic on [cs.se] where it's been [reposted](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/determine-if-either-of-both-languages-are-ambiguous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is ambiguous and the second is not. This is a question about how a context-free grammar (CFG) can be turned into a parse tree. In the first CFG, the first production   is the source of the ambiguity. If I write the string "()()()" it is unclear which part of this string could match the left non-terminal and which could match the right non-terminal.

One valid parse tree for that string is that the first two characters "()" match the first non-terminal, which then matches the second production and the rest of the string "()()" matches the right non-terminal, which again matches the first production again.

Another valid parse tree is for the first four characters "()()" to match the left non-terminal and for the rest "()" to match the right non-terminal. Both are equally valid so there is an ambiguity. Parser tools like LR parsers call this a shift/reduce conflict.

This has absolutely no problem if you just want to see if a string belongs to a language. If any parse works, you're good. This has really problematic effects, however, if you're trying to create a parse tree to use as, for example, an abstract syntax tree for a programming language.

To show why this is a problem for parsing a language take a look at this example.

```
 <expression> ::= <expression> <expression> | <expression> + <expression> | <expression> * <expression>
```

How do you parse "1+2*3"? Is it "(1+2)*3" or "1+(2*3)"? The grammar I gave has a shift/reduce conflict so it is not specified. Most LR parse tools will resolve this conflict for you automatically an arbitrarily. This is dangerous because if I'm writing a programming language there should be a well-defined understanding of which the programmer will get. Since this is a typical arithmetic expression we should probably follow the math convention and have the answer be "1+(2*3)".

The solution is to rewrite the grammar so that it's unambiguous or many parser tools also just allow us to explicitly specify the associativity and precedence of our lexical symbols, which is very convenient for keeping your grammar nice and readable.